# apt-get - autoremove wants to uninstall Gnome

Tags: debian, apt

As empathy 2.30 in Debian Wheezy didn't meet all my preferences I tried out empathy 3.1 from experimental, using the command:

```
apt-get -t experimental install empathy
```

I had to find out, this version of empathy doesn't work well in Gnome 2.x. Therefore I mentioned:

```
apt-get purge empathy
apt-get install empathy
```

Hoping, that this will reinstall the "standard" version of empathy again.

So far, everything worked well.

But now:

```
apt-get autoremove
```

wants to delete Gnome as a whole.

How can I calm down `apt-get autoremove`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

APT maintains an indicator for each package, telling it whether the package is *manually installed* (installed because the user/administrator wanted it) or *automatically installed* (installed only because it's a dependency of some other package). That's what `apt-get autoremove` uses to determine what to remove: it removes packages that are marked as automatically installed, but that no currently installed package requires.

You need to mark the `gnome` package, or whatever Gnome package corresponds to the bits you want to keep, as manually installed. It's easiest to do this in an interactive tool with access to the automatically-installed setting:

- On the command line, call `aptitude unmarkauto PACKAGENAME` to mark PACKAGENAME as manually installed, or `markauto` to mark it as automatically installed.
- In Aptitude, move to the line corresponding to a package, then press `m` to mark it as manually installed, or `M` to mark it as automatically installed.
- In Synaptic, move to the line corresponding to a package, then toggle “Automatically installed” in the “Package” menu.

Note that (at least as of squeeze, I haven't checked wheezy) `gnome-desktop-environment` depends on all of the official Gnome components, including empathy. I suspect you had `gnome-desktop-environment` installed, and removing the `empathy` package had to remove it because of the dependency. If this is the case you should now reinstall `gnome-desktop-environment`. (If you don't remember, you can find a history of what APT-based package managers did in `/var/log/apt`.)

Instead of purging and installing `empathy`, you could have just done `apt-get -t wheezy empathy` to install the wheezy version.

Comment: cool! Using this "trick" one could remove Empathy without removing Gnome, right?

Comment: @Marcel: You can remove Empathy without removing other Gnome components, but the `gnome-desktop-environment` package depends on `empathy`, so you must have removed that, and probably want to reinstall it.

Answer (score 8):

You can `apt-get install` some gnome package (which is already installed) to set it as manually selected (installed). This should introduce the needed dependencies such that autoremove does not want to remove the gnome packages anymore.

I am not using gnome, but probably there is some gnome-desktop package or something like that which pulls in all the main gnome stuff.

For example the output on my system for a non-gnome package:

```
# apt-get install libsource-highlight3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libsource-highlight3 is already the newest version.
libsource-highlight3 set to manually installed.
```

`libsource-highlight3` was automatically installed as dependency of `source-highlight`. After the remove  of `source-highlight`, `apt-get autoremove` would not remove the `libsource-highlight3` package, because it is *set to manually installed* now.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your suggestion and mentioned `apt-get install gnome` in the command line. Debian now wants to use 200MB additional diskspace, which I find kind of strange - however, I hope that works.

Comment: @Marcel, this should be ok - probably the application package or packages (which pulled your current gnome packaged as dependencies (e.g. empathy) and were later removed) just don't need all of gnome - a main gnome package on the other hand wants to provide the whole gnome desktop, i.e. it depends on all gnome packages which are considered as the default gnome experience.

Comment: @Marcel: you don't need to do `apt-get install gnome`. @maxshekepzig was suggesting `apt-get install`  for some package you already have installed.

Comment: @Faheem you are right. `apt-get install gnome` would pull all those other packages. Therefore I didn't need to search for a `gnome-desktop` package (in the meantime I think it's called `gnome-core`).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to completelly switch off autoremove with these options (in /etc/apt/apt.conf orn in file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ directory):

```
APT::Get::AutomaticRemove "0";
APT::Get::HideAutoRemove "1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the list of packages apt is wanting to autoremove (use a text editor to remove trailing whitespace). Then `sudo apt install <paste list of packages>` fixed this issue for me on numerous occasions. Its simply a difference of packages being manually installed (apt thinks you must need these as you installed them) vs. packages being automatically installed (apt installed these so it assumes it can do what it wants with them). By doing th above you tell apt that they are all mannually installed. FYI - I sometimes have to do this twice as it will continue to suggest further autoremoves.