# How can I prevent Apt-Get from autoremoving packages?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [apt-get - autoremove wants to uninstall Gnome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14310/apt-get-autoremove-wants-to-uninstall-gnome)

I'm running Debian@ [edit: kernel] 3.0 with Gnome. 
apt-get wants to autoremove dozens of packages. How can I prevent it from doing so? It seems as if I have removed a meta-package. 
The autoremove output looks as follows:

```
# apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  baobab freedesktop-sound-theme freeglut3 gcalctool gconf-editor gdebi
  gdebi-core gir1.2-vte-2.90 gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-backgrounds
  gnome-cards-data gnome-games gnome-games-data gnome-games-extra-data
  gnome-nettool gnome-office gnome-screenshot gnome-search-tool
  gnome-session-canberra gnome-system-log gnome-system-tools
  gnome-video-effects gstreamer0.10-nice gucharmap guile-1.8-libs inkscape
  libaiksaurus-1.2-0c2a libaiksaurus-1.2-data libaiksaurusgtk-1.2-0c2a
  libavahi-gobject0 libchamplain-0.8-1 libchamplain-gtk-0.8-1
  libclutter-gst-1.0-0 libclutter-gtk-0.10-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
  libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0 libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0 libcryptui0a libdiscid0
  libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp0 libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a
  libgee2 libgexiv2-0 libgnome2-canvas-perl libgnome2-perl libgnome2-vfs-perl
  libgoffice-0.8-8 libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgpod-common libgpod4
  libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgssdp-1.0-2 libgstfarsight0.10-0
  libgtkglext1 libgtkhtml-editor-3.14-0 libgtkhtml-editor-3.14-common
  libgtkhtml3.14-19 libgtkmathview0c2a libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgucharmap-2-90-7
  libgupnp-1.0-3 libgupnp-igd-1.0-3 libimobiledevice1 liblink-grammar4
  libloudmouth1-0 libmission-control-plugins0 libmusicbrainz3-6 libmx-1.0-2
  libnet1 libnice10 libnm-glib2 libnm-util1 libopal3.6.8 libots0 libpt2.6.7
  libraw2 libsrtp0 libssh-4 libtelepathy-farsight0 libtelepathy-glib0
  libwebkit-1.0-2 libwebkit-1.0-common libwv-1.2-3 libxcb-render-util0
  link-grammar-dictionaries-en media-player-info mousetweaks perlmagick
  python-bugbuddy python-gtkglext1 python-mako python-markupsafe python-opengl
  python-webkit remmina remmina-plugin-data remmina-plugin-rdp
  remmina-plugin-vnc rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugins
  seahorse shotwell simple-scan software-center sound-juicer tcptraceroute
  telepathy-gabble telepathy-mission-control-5 telepathy-salut
  transmission-common transmission-gtk update-manager-core
  update-manager-gnome update-notifier update-notifier-common vino
  xdg-user-dirs-gtk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 121 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 370 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: debian 3.0? Seriously? The current stable is 6.0, even 4.0 is expected to start acting up by now...

Comment: You are in no way forced to run that command, so live with it

Comment: tdammers, sorry, what I mean is _kernel_ 3.0 ;-D
 -- enzotib, that's not an option. But thanks, though!