# uninstalling iceweasel with apt-get autoremove

Tags: debian, apt, firefox

When I try to uninstall iceweasel it wants to uninstall dependencies like 'gnome' and 'gnome-core', which of course I don't want. I tried to follow several instructions in [apt-get - autoremove wants to uninstall Gnome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14310/apt-get-autoremove-wants-to-uninstall-gnome)
... but to no avail.

A clue would maybe be that something messed up when I installed kde to give it a try ( now I am back on gnome2 ).

If someone has already been in my case ...

Comment: How about using `apt-get purge iceweasel`? It would remove Iceweasel, as well as, its configuration files.

Comment: no it does not change anything Barun, it does not change anything ...

Answer (score 4):

In my Debian install, `gnome-core` has a required dependency on `iceweasel`.  If you attempt to uninstall `iceweasel`, you by definition break the `gnome-core` installation, which means it needs to be uninstalled as well.  And `gnome` has a required dependency on `gnome-core`; rinse, repeat.  So, you're kinda stuck.

This state of affairs is arguably a GNOME packaging bug, and `gnome-core` should more properly be depending on the virtual package `gnome-www-browser` or `www-browser`.

Answer (score 3):

You need only to mark the package it wants to remove as manual installed. Lets say:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove iceweasel
The following packages will be removed:
  iceweasel gnome
```

If there's a package you don't want to remove you only do:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
gnome is already installed
marked as installed manually
```

Then when you remove iceweasel, it doesn't try to remove gnome. Done.

Answer (score 1):

The gnome and gnome-core packages are *meta*-packages. They don't contain any files, just dependencies on other packages. So technically you don't need them and you won't be adversely affected. If you uninstall iceweasel, gnome and gnome-core, the only thing you'll be missing is iceweasel.

What you *will* miss, is if in the *next* version of Debian gnome or gnome-core depend on new additional packages they won't be automatically installed by the dependency graph.