# Debian installs new, non depended on packages

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I recently dist-upgraded my jessie box and several new packages were installed. It looks like there were no packages that depend on the new packages, as I could autoremove them flawlessly.
An example is ruby, which was not installed before and got pulled in during the last upgrade. It is marked as auto.

Is there something in apt that I don't understand? I don't want new, non-critical packages installed, unless I specify it.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14310/apt-get-autoremove-wants-to-uninstall-gnome